# How do I pass v-on/v-bind to component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am working with Vuetify menu and button components. I am trying to pass the menu and attrs from the activator slot in the template in SomeFile.vue into the v-btn in the MyCustomButtonTemplate.vue file, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  Does anyone know how to correctly pass those values?  A bare bones example is shown below

`SomeFile.vue`

```html
<v-menu offset-y>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu, attrs }">
    <MyCustomButtonTemplate v-on="menu" v-bind="attrs">
  </template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-title>Some Title</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

`MyCustomButtonTemplate.vue`

```html
<template>
  <v-tooltip top>
    <template #activator="{ on: tooltip }">
      <v-btn v-on="{...tooltip, ...menu}" v-bind="attrs">Blah</v-btn>
    </template>
    <span>Some tooltip</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

Comment: How about this: `<v-btn v-on="{...tooltip, ...$listeners}" v-bind="$attrs">Blah</v-btn>`

Comment: When I click on the menu button I get 'Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"'

Comment: As stated by @Mr.R, `$listeners` includes all event handlers passed from parent and `$attrs` - all attributes. See this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-play-forked-4pzq89?file=/src/components/customButton.vue), and try to reproduce the error that you are getting.

Comment: Hi Igor, that was a big help, thanks! I noticed that the menu items get knocked out of whack though. They end up in the top left corner with no line breaks per menu item. I can add 'absolute' to the v-menu and css to the list-items to get it closer to what it should be, but I'm wondering if somethings still off with the code that's causing that behavior. Thoughts?

Comment: @IgorMoraru, btw your code seems to work. If you open up a post I can award you the bounty

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 the problem was with my codesandbox using an old vuetify version. also, after adding some vuetify grid stuff, the menu is displayed nicely. I have posted my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access component event listeners and attributes in `$listeners` and `$attrs` objects. Also you can pass them to children with additional event handlers and listeners by destructuring them.

```html
<v-tooltip top>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn v-on="{ ...on, ...$listeners }" v-bind="$attrs">Blah</v-btn>
    </template>
    <span>Some tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-play-forked-4pzq89?file=/src/components/customButton.vue:41-242)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make `inheritAttrs` to false in custom component, because by default vue for bindings will apply to the root element of the child component as normal HTML attributes.

```
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

then you can apply attributes and listeners on your element in custom component.

```html
<template>
  <v-tooltip top>
    <template #activator="{ on: tooltip }">
      <v-btn v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...$listeners }" v-bind="$attrs">Blah</v-btn>
    </template>
    <span>Some tooltip</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

BTW you didnt define `menu` and `attrs` as props but you used it like you have it in your component. Most of reserved methods and properties that we use in vue starts with `$`. Of course this is true only for Options API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm not clear on a few things.  Which file does the inheritAttrs go in? What do I do with menu/attrs in SomeFile.vue? If I don't pass those to the MyCustomButtonTemplate component I get eslint errors saying the values are unused.

Comment: the parent stays the same. in another words `$listeners` and `$attrs` will bind your events and attributes to element you want